# How to access MainPage.xaml controls from another page

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-store-apps

i have an image element in the MainPage.xaml and a flyout in SettingsContract1.xaml, when the flyout item is clicked the filepicker is opened and i want to set them image source of the image in the Mainpage with the file picked from the filepicker. How can i access the image from SettingsContract1.xaml

image in MainPage.xaml

```
<Image x:Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="332" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="778" Margin="349,406,0,0"/>
```

menuflyout sub in SettingsContract1.xaml

```
Private Sub chooseFile_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles chooseFile.Click
    Dim filePicker As FileOpenPicker
    filePicker = New FileOpenPicker()
    filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png")
    Dim file As StorageFile = Await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync()

    Using filestream As Streams.IRandomAccessStream = Await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)
        Dim bitmapImage As Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage = New BitmapImage
        bitmapImage.SetSource(filestream)
        img.Source = bitmapImage 'gives an error
    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419875/windows-8-app-accessing-page-method-from-app-xaml-cs) and converted it to VB

```
Private Async Sub chooseFile_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles chooseFile.Click
    Dim mapImage As Frame = Window.Current.Content
    Dim mainPage As MainPage = mapImage.Content
    Dim filePicker As FileOpenPicker
    filePicker = New FileOpenPicker()
    filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png")
    Dim file As StorageFile = Await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync()

    Using filestream As Streams.IRandomAccessStream = Await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)
        Dim bitmapImage As Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage = New BitmapImage
        bitmapImage.SetSource(filestream)
        mainPage.img.Source = bitmapImage
    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable that is mapped to the `MainPage` and then access any public member form there.

```
Dim mp = TryCast(Application.Current.RootVisual, MainPage)
If Not mp Is Nothing Then
  mp.img.Source = bitmapImage
End If
```